# Python conflict when installing Cloud-Init

Tags: python, centos, yum, cloud-init

I have a CentOS 6.0 Virtual Machine. I'm trying to install cloud-init (related to AWS) on it. I run

```
yum install cloud-init
```

Then, I see that cloud-init is dependent on a number of python packages.

[image]

After I accept the installation (with "y"), I see hundreds of errors like this:

```
file /usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.pyc from install of python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.pyo from install of python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.pyc from install of python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.pyo from install of python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.x86_64
```

usr/bin/python -V returns Python 2.6.5, so it seems the virtual machine is using this version, and the dependencies are using 2.6.6. However -- I don't see why cloud-init can't just use 2.6.6 when the system is using 2.6.5. Why is the installation of cloud-init failing with the "conflicts with file" errors?

Comment: You should do a full update of the system first.

Comment: You mean of the OS? Using CentOS 6.0 happens to be a constraint, unfortunately :(

Comment: No, I was talking about a `yum upgrade`.

Comment: This fixed the problem! Can you explain why? Was it because 2.5.5 was deleted (since it was obsolete), or for some other reason?

Comment: It was a typical dependency problem when you install software on a outdated system. An example: The outdated package requires libxyz version 1.0.1 and the new to install package requires the version 1.0.2. Both can't be satisfied. When you update the old package the dependency will change to 1.0.2 and all is fine.

Comment: Thanks -- that makes sense! Possibly silly question: why can't one package use one version and the other use the other version?

Comment: Not with system packages and yum. For Python development [virtual environments](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) solve that problem.